# Уникальный Url после отправки формы Cf7

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Я использую такой код

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
       location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you/';
}, false );
</script>
```

Мне надо чтобы был редирект на `https://www.example.com/thank-you/` эту страницу только чтобы был уникальный url.
Страница `thanks-you` уже создана в разделе Страниц в админке вордпресса по такому URL `https://www.example.com/thank-you/` надо , чтобы после отправки перескакивал на эту страницу `https://www.example.com/thank-you/` но URL должен быть таким к примеру `https://www.example.com/thank-you/dfdsfdsgdfg` уникальным.
Чтобы не показывал 404 ,  а  вот именно страницу `https://www.example.com/thank-you/`  только по уникальному URL

Comment: Поясните, для чего это нужно

Comment: Используйте GET-параметры

Comment: Без контекста не понятно для чего тебе нужен уникальный URL, возможно тебе помогут параметры поиска `https://www.example.com/thank-you?ts=1589554419997` , Date.now()